# How to extract(parse) integers from a continuous string in Go Lang

Tags: parsing, go

I have very large(potentially endless) stream of integers similar to input below.

I intend to randomly access this slice and read from string one character at a time, and would like to access the integer represented by the character.

For the code below I was expecting intVal to be an integer value of 3. number[1] gives me the ASCII code for 3 which is 51.

```
input := "2345892345234502349502345234534234572304520345902384523045"
intVal,_ := strconv.Atoi(input[1])
```

Essentially, What is the proper way of reading integers from strings in Go ?

Comment: The answer is `strconv.Atoi`, like in your example. It is fast and safe. 
BUT!!!!! You should not omit the second parameter. Handle and check the error. Inside your string could be also something different.

Comment: Am I the only one getting this error when try to execute the OP's code *cannot use input[1] (type byte) as type string in argument to strconv.Atoi*

Comment: I think you mean something like this https://play.golang.org/p/P0rt1HD65iK and it works as you expected.

Comment: This is an example of how I was expecting it to work. Yes this should give you an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to get the numeric value of the decimal number at `input[i]`:

```
b := input[i]
if b < '0' || b > '9' {
    // not a decimal number
    ... handle error here
}
n := int(b) - '0'
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can read one rune at a time and convert to string:

```
for _,r:=range input {
   str:=string(r)
}
```

Or access randomly:

```
str:=input[n:n+1]
```